# Ruby - Cannot Load File (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, rubygems

I installed the ruby-aaws gem and I tried to run a sample script. I Get the following error. Is there something I am missing ?Thanks.

```
1. gem install ruby-aaws

2. amazon.rb

require 'amazon/aws'
require 'amazon/aws/search'

include Amazon::AWS
include Amazon::AWS::Search

ASSOCIATES_ID = "************"
KEY_ID = '**************'

il = ItemLookup.new( 'ASIN', { 'ItemId' => 'B001COU9I6',
'MerchantId' => 'Amazon' })

rg = ResponseGroup.new( 'Medium' )

req = Request.new(KEY_ID, ASSOCIATES_ID)

resp = req.search( il, rg)
item_sets = resp.item_lookup_response[0].items
item_sets.each do |item_set|
item_set.item.each do |item|
attribs = item.item_attributes[0]
puts attribs
end
end
```

> 3. (ERROR)
>
>    $ ruby amazon.rb
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require': cannot load such file -- iconv (LoadError)
>             from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'
>             from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-aaws-0.8.1/lib/amazon/aws.rb:12:in
>   `<module:AWS>'
>             from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-aaws-0.8.1/lib/amazon/aws.rb:7:in`
>   '
>             from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-aaws-0.8.1/lib/amazon/aws.rb:5:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>             from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in`
>   require'
>             from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in
>   `rescue in require'
>             from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in`
>   require'
>             from amazon.rb:7:in `'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing `iconv` in your system, or your version doesn't match requirements from other packages.

#### Check if you have `iconv` installed

```
iconv --version
```

or

```
which iconv
```

#### Install `iconv` gem

```
gem install iconv
```

or

```
rvm pkg install iconv
```

#### If nothing works, try older/other versions

```
gem install iconv -v '~> 1.0.3'
```